# Front Derailleur Tuning Question

Tags: road-bike, derailleur, adjustment

I've installed new front derailleur (Shimano Tiagra) on my bike and I spent embarrassingly lots of time trying to adjust it. Yet still I think I have a problem with it. For me it seems too tense. You need to apply some strength to the shifter in order to make the derailleur switch to the larger gear. When I try to go to the lower gear it does it with a scarily loud sound.

All that I can think of is that the spring in the derailleur is too tense. Yet I see no means to adjust the tension of the spring. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks guys! You're the best as always!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spring tension of front derailleurs is not normally configurable.

Addressing your difficulty shifting up, have you checked whether the **H**igh limit screw is preventing the mech from moving all the way, forcing you to stretch the cable until the shifter reaches the ratchet point?

The shifter is normally able to freely pull cable slightly beyond the ratchet point to allow you to ensure a successful shift, releasing the tension until the ratchet point so that the cage does not foul the chain running on the selected chainring.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I checked the both screws. nothing preventing derailleur to go up and down.

Comment: You can check the free movement of the cage by unclamping the cable and moving the cage with your hand. Alternatively, just turn out (anti-clockwise) the High limit screw completely just to be sure it is not the problem.